# Foreign key column optionally contains NULL or ID. Is there a better design?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on a database that holds answers from a questionnaire for companies.
In the table that holds the bulk of the answers I have a column (ie techDir) that indicates whether there is technical director. If the company has a director then it's populated with an ID referencing a "people" table, else it holds "null".

Another design that has come to mind is the "techDir" column holding a Boolean value, leaving the look-up in the "people" table to the software logic and adding a column in the "people" table indicating the role of the person.

Which of the two designs is better? Is there generally a better design that I have not thought of?

Comment: Very nice stuff from everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that if there is a relatively small amount of NULL values, then using NULLs would be okay. However, if you find that most rows contain NULLs, then you might be better off deleting the techDir column and placing a column referencing the "Answers" into a new table alongside another field referencing the "People" table. In other words, create an intermediate table between the Answers table and the People table containing all technical directors as shown below.

[image]

This will get rid of all the NULL values and also allow for more flexibility. If there is only one Technical Director per answer then simply make the column referencing the answers table "Unique" to create a One-to-One relationship. If you need more than one technical director, create a One-to-Many relationship as shown. Another advantage to this design is that it simplifies the query if you ever want to extract all the technical directors. I generally use a simple rule of thumb when deciding whether to use NULL values or not. If I see the table contains lots of NULLS, I remove those columns and create a new table where I can store that data. You should of course also consider the types of queries you will be executing. For example, the design above might require an Inner or Outer Join to view all the rows including the technical directors. As a developer, you should carefully weigh up the pros and cons and look at things like flexibility, speed, complexity and your business rules when making these decisions.

Answer (score 1):

Logically, if there is no director, there should be `NULL`.

In bussiness logic, you would have a reference to a `Director` object there, if there is no director, there should also be `null` instead of the reference.

Using a boolean in fear of additional performance loss due to longer query time looks very much like premature optimisation.
Also there are *joins* that are optimized to do that efficiently in one query, so no additional lookups are necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by "there should not be NULL." ? This has nothing to do with bussiness logic, this is database design.

Comment: @Nanne: Thanks, it was a typo. I guess I was going to type *there should not be an ID* but changed it and forgot to remove the *not*. Fixed!

Comment: "Logically, if there is no director, there should not be NULL."

I assume you meant "there should be null"?

It's not really optimization I'm worried about at this point, rather than building a database that relies on software logic to hold it all together instead of using relations. You could say that I'm worried about the "principal" of it :)

Comment: @jimmy: Well, that depends solely on the relation of answers and directors. Since you haven't specified it, I assumed there will be a different director assigned to different answers, in case of different directors, there should be a table of relations between them. In case where any director has relation to any answer that `hasDirector`, your another design would be correct. Since you have specified the ID way, it seemed that each answer can only have one director!

Answer (score 0):

You could argue that it depends on how many people have a director, so you could save a little space when only 1 in a million entries has one, depeding on the datatype you use. But in the end, clearest (and best) option is to indeed make a foreign key that allows for NULL, like you proposed in the first option.

Comment: You only have to be aware of a fact that you will have same information on two places. If technical director changes, in this table you will still have the old value. But, again, this can be good, if you want to have history of changes. I would also go with NULL-able FK design.

Answer (score 0):

I think the null for that column is ok. As far as I remember from my DB class at uni (long time ago), **null** is an excellent choice to represent "I don't know" or "it doesn't have".

I think the second design has the following flaw: You didn't mentioned how to look up for the techdir of a specific question, you said that you just tag the person. Another problem might be that if in the future you add another role, the schema won't support it.

Comment: Hi Augusto, that could be done by using the question ID as a primary key in the people table (as in "these people belong to this question") and using a WHERE clause to filter for the "techDir" role.

Comment: My bad, you would need to use a composite primary key ie questionID + roleID

Answer (score 0):

NULL is the most common way of indicating no relationship in an optional relationship.

There is an alternative.  Decompose the table into two tables, one of which is has two foreign keys, back to the original table and forward to the related table.  In cases where there is no relationship, just omit the entire row.

If you want to understand this in terms of normalization, look up "Sixth Normal form" (6NF).  Not all experts are in agreement about 6NF.